# Gradient Panel shows red cross when minimized and then restored

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, panel, gradient

I have no idea why this is happening, but I created the below code which is a gradient panel, the panel is then docked to the left of the screen.

When the form is re-sized it displays correctly, however if you minimize the form and then restore it you get a big red X instead of the gradient.

Can anyone spot the error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class GradientPanel : Panel
{
    private Color ColorA = Color.LightBlue;
    private Color ColorB = Color.Red;
    private LinearGradientMode GradientFillStyle = LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal;
    private Brush gradientBrush;

    public Color colourStart
    {
        get { return ColorA; }
        set { ColorA = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Color colourEnd
    {
        get { return ColorB; }
        set { ColorB = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public LinearGradientMode colourGradientStyle
    {
        get { return GradientFillStyle; }
        set { GradientFillStyle = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    public GradientPanel()
    {
        handlerGradientChanged = new EventHandler(GradientChanged);
        ResizeRedraw = true;        
    }

    private EventHandler handlerGradientChanged;

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, ColorA, ColorB, GradientFillStyle);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, ClientRectangle);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (gradientBrush != null) gradientBrush.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        Invalidate();
        //base.OnResize(eventargs);
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
        //base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }
    private void GradientChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gradientBrush != null) gradientBrush.Dispose();
        gradientBrush = null;
        Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would avoid creating a new `LinearGradientBrush` in the `OnPaintBackground` handler. My guess is you could be hitting your GDI object limit (which you can check in task manager) as I don't think you are disposing your brushes correctly. Move this to the constructor, or in a function that is called when the colours and styles properties change (and dispose of the previous before creating the new one)

Comment: @musefan Thanks for that, I moved it into the constructor but it now ignores the paramaters given to it (instead of showing the darkred to red horizontal gradient it shows the default shown in the code) How do I get around this as I've never come accorss it before

Comment: I posted you an answer to explain it more, I hope it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid creating a new `LinearGradientBrush` in the `OnPaintBackground` handler.

My guess is you could be hitting your GDI object limit (which you can check in task manager) as I don't think you are disposing your brushes correctly.

Move this to the constructor, or in a function that is called when the colours and styles properties change (and dispose of the previous before creating the new one)

Here is an example of what you can do while still allowing the properties to change the colours etc...

Edit properties:

```
public Color colourStart
{
    get { return ColorA; }
    set { ColorA = value; RefershBrush(); }
}
public Color colourEnd
{
    get { return ColorB; }
    set { ColorB = value; RefershBrush(); }
}
public LinearGradientMode colourGradientStyle
{
    get { return GradientFillStyle; }
    set { GradientFillStyle = value; RefershBrush(); }
}
```

Add function:

```
private void RefershBrush()
{
    //I think this IF block should work with no problems, been a while working with brush
    if(gradientBrush != null)
    {
        gradientBrush.Dispose();
    }

    gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, ColorA, ColorB, GradientFillStyle);
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @Neo, this might be worth a read fi you get the chance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165443/Disposing-GDI-Objects-in-C-NET ...although it didn't really get a great reception from readers it does detail the pains I have had with things like you have seen today, and I think there is some useful things to know in there. plus you can read the comments for any recommendations from other readers

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing something similar, but even cleaning up the `LinearGradientBrush` didn't fix it for me.  Looking at the console output, I noticed "A first chance exception of type `System.ArgumentException` occurred in System.Drawing.dll."  I believe this is because the ClientRectangle is 0,0 when the component is minimized.  Adding this code seemed to fix it for me:

```
  protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnPaintBackground(e);
     if (this.gradientBrush != null)
        this.gradientBrush.Dispose();
     if (this.ClientRectangle.Width > 0 && this.ClientRectangle.Height > 0)
     {
        this.gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
           FROM_GRADIENT_COLOR, TO_GRADIENT_COLOR, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(this.gradientBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are disposing of the Brush correctly.

Refactored code:

```
public class GradientPanel : Panel {
  private Color ColorA = Color.LightBlue;
  private Color ColorB = Color.Red;
  private LinearGradientMode GradientFillStyle = LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal;

  public GradientPanel() {
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    ResizeRedraw = true;
  }

  public Color colourStart {
    get { return ColorA; }
    set { ColorA = value; Invalidate(); }
  }

  public Color colourEnd {
    get { return ColorB; }
    set { ColorB = value; Invalidate(); }
  }

  public LinearGradientMode colourGradientStyle {
    get { return GradientFillStyle; }
    set { GradientFillStyle = value; Invalidate(); }
  }

  protected override void OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {
    using (var gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, ColorA, ColorB, GradientFillStyle)) {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, ClientRectangle);
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to invalidate on every Resize or SizeChanged because you already have the control set with the `ResizeRedraw=True` property.  I added the `DoubleBuffered=True` property as well to control flickering.

I placed your Gradient brush in a `Using()` block so that it will get disposed.

Comment: I tried your method, still came up with the red cross but a +1 for the doublebuffered and using :)

Comment: @Neo You are most likely running out of resources somewhere else then.  Make sure in any other controls or forms that you are displaying that you are properly disposing of objects.  Open up Task Manager and under processes, show the "GDI Objects" column, and watch the value on your exe as you run your program, especially when you minimize and restore.  If the number keeps going up, you are leaking resources.