# Transparent label vanishing on resize

Tags: c#, winforms, label, transparency, transparent

Yet again another issue with resizing, like many others I have used the CreateParams method of setting up a transparent label, everything looks and works great... except for when the form is re-sized the text vanishes!

Anyone have any ideas?  The control is there but the text isn't showing as if I minimize the form and then restore it shows!

```
public class TransparentLabel : Label
{
    public TransparentLabel()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
            parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return parms;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (base.BackgroundImage == null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(this.BackColor, 1), e.ClipRectangle);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9377337/719186).  Your form is most likely leaking resources.  On its own, the example code above does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for that I spotted that a few moments ago but I can't see where it is leaking resources.  sorry re-phrase that the GDI objects are staying at 85 constantly, I am however leaking memory from somewhere

Comment: I figured out the memory leak was report viewer which has been resolved.  Still no idea why the labels vanish :(

Comment: May be a `myLabel.Invalidate()` after resize can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background Label over PictureBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387267/transparent-background-label-over-picturebox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution to this was to use a Link Label control, set its background to transparent and set the link length to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code it appears that the control is being drawn over by any controls that should be under it in the Z order. You may need to redraw the text by responding to the right paint message. I found an example of a TransparentLabel [here](http://www.doogal.co.uk/transparent.php) that seems to do this.