# Winform gradient error after maximizing after minimizing

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient

I created a gradient for my form background but Im having this issue now. In winforms, when I minimize and then maximize the form i get this:

[imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/errorbl.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1180/errorbl.png).

I guess the bug is that the form has to redraw itself after maximizing and it doesn't. Somebody knows how to solve it?

Thanks!

Calling gradient:

```
public Base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form_Background);

    }
```

Gradient method:

```
public void Form_Background(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 252, 254, 255);
        Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 247, 251, 253);
        Color c3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 228, 239, 247);
        Color c4 = Color.FromArgb(255, 217, 228, 238);
        Color c5 = Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 212, 217);
        Color c6 = Color.FromArgb(255, 177, 198, 215);
        Color c7 = Color.FromArgb(255, 166, 186, 208);

        LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, c1, c7, 90, true);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.146, (float)0.317, (float)0.439, (float)0.585, (float)0.797, 1 };
        cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 };
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;


        // paint
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
```

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377337/gradient-panel-shows-red-cross-when-minimized-and-then-restored

Comment: We'll need to see the code that draws the gradient...

Comment: I updated the post now with that info. keyboardP, yes, its related, but i dont get what is he doing in that solution. I used Colorblend too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that width and height of `this.ClientRectangle` is zero after being minimized.

You need to implement a check of the rectangle before applying any gradient and drawing with it:

```
Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;

if (r.Width > 0 && r.Height > 0) {

    //draw

}
```

So your code would like something like this:

```
public void Form_Background(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

    Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;

    if (r.Width > 0 && r.Height > 0) {

        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(252, 254, 255);
        Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(247, 251, 253);
        Color c3 = Color.FromArgb(228, 239, 247);
        Color c4 = Color.FromArgb(217, 228, 238);
        Color c5 = Color.FromArgb(200, 212, 217);
        Color c6 = Color.FromArgb(177, 198, 215);
        Color c7 = Color.FromArgb(166, 186, 208);

        LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(r, c1, c7, 90, true);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.146, (float)0.317, _
                                  (float)0.439, (float)0.585, _
                                  (float)0.797, 1 };

        cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 };
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;

        // paint
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r);

        br.Dispose; //added dispose for the brush

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That was dumb! Thank you so much for your answer! It´s working now.

Comment: You can also check This.ClientRectangle.Size.IsEmpty

Comment: Also, it will remain black after resizing unless you override the constructor to redraw on resize.  ie public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494234/c-sharp-lineargradientbrush-glitch-when-minimizing-screen