# C# LinearGradientBrush glitch when minimizing screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have the following code to create a blended background on my winform:

```
public partial class Aging : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
        Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            var blend = new ColorBlend();
            blend.Positions = new[] { 0, 3 / 10f, 1 };
            blend.Colors = new[] { Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.LightSteelBlue };
            brush.InterpolationColors = blend;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
```

The result is a color background that fades from LightSteelBlue to WhiteSmoke:

[image]

The problem is that if I minimize the screen and then, maximize, the application no longer shows the background:

[image]

This is the exception message I'm getting:

```
System.ArgumentException: Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height equal to 0.
at System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush..ctor(Rectangle rect, Color color1, Color color2, LinearGradientMode linearGradientMode)
at AgingStatusDb.Aging.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,  
IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I'm not that savvy and I'm not been able to figure out the source of the glitch. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May have already happened when minimizing. Best add a check for width>0 at the start.. Can't reproduce it here though. But the error mentions a  `Rectangle rect`, not in your code!?!

Comment: Well, it does show the background but it is now the Red Cross of Failure.  And will stay that way, once your painting code crashed it will not try to run it again to avoid a storm of exceptions.  The exception message you get is very good, you can't create a brush that is 0x0 pixels.  That's very easy to check in your OnPaintBackground() method, do nothing if CllientRectangle.Width or Height is 0.

Comment: Just checking for zero width or height is not enough. You should also set `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` in constructor. Also you need to set `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` to redraw the form when you resize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the exception, just follow what the exception message said:

> Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height
>   equal to 0.

So you can simply check if `ClientRectangle.Width==0` or  `ClientRectangle.Height==0` then do nothing and just return.

**But after fixing the error you will have a black background after a minimize and restore.**

If you want to draw background of a form, above code needs some corrections:

- You need to set control to redraw itself when resized. To do so, you should set `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` in constructor.
- You need to enable double buffering to prevent flicker. So in constructor set `this.DoubleBuffered = true;`.

**Code**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (ClientRectangle.Width == 0 || ClientRectangle.Height == 0) return;
    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
        Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
    {
        var b = new ColorBlend();
        b.Positions = new[] { 0, 3 / 10f, 1 };
        b.Colors = new[] { Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.LightSteelBlue };
        brush.InterpolationColors = b;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, I was way off on the way I was trying to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is simplest way to do fading background.

Create an image with a gradient in a graphics editor or using your code, but save it:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
        Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
    {
        var blend = new ColorBlend();
        blend.Positions = new[] { 0, 3 / 10f, 1 };
        blend.Colors = new[] { Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.LightSteelBlue };
        brush.InterpolationColors = blend;

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height))
        {
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
            bmp.Save("background.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

Run and close the app. Then remove that code.

In the end, set the form background image, which was created in the previous step:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("background.png");
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the answer. The first answer worked out better as I need a dynamic background for my project. Unfortunately, a set bmp image is not functional enough for what I need.