# Is there a way to specify the dimensions of background color of a control in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, backcolor

Looking at the guide on MSDN to override a control's default [backColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx), it's my understanding that the color applies to the entire control. Does anyone know if  there's a way to apply a new background color only to a specific area of the control, though? For instance, if I only wanted to color half of a button? Thanks!

Comment: You would have to paint it yourself.

Comment: Paint the background yourself

Comment: I see. Thanks guys

Comment: For example, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40494234/3110834).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# LinearGradientBrush glitch when minimizing screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494234/c-sharp-lineargradientbrush-glitch-when-minimizing-screen)